# RegEx: Reject sub-portion of complicated expression

Tags: regex, notepad++

In the sample text below, I want to match groups of text (newlines and all) starting with a line defined by `\nI.*'` and including the subsequent lines starting with `\nA`, only if *none* of the *intermediate* lines contains "BOM=". I.e. in the example, I would want to match the first "device" and its following attributes, but not the second device, as shown in my comments (after `#`s).

```
I 657 device:THAT 2 1290 400 0 1 ' # Start matching here because no lines have "BOM="
A 1335 425 12 0 5 0 some text
A 1335 455 12 0 5 0 some text
A 1300 440 12 0 9 3 some text
A 1370 375 12 0 3 0 some text # Finish matching here
C 655 1 3 0
A 1370 450 12 0 3 3 #=2
C 740 2 4 0
A 1305 450 12 0 9 3 #=1
C 740 2 4 0
A 1305 450 12 0 9 3 #=1

I 318 device:THIS 2 300 1840 0 1 ' # Do not match again here because there's a line with "BOM="
A 320 1880 12 0 7 3 some text
A 320 1880 12 0 9 3 some text
A 380 1880 12 0 1 1 BOM=1,2
A 345 1865 12 0 5 0 some text
A 380 1830 12 0 3 0 some text 
C 666 1 3 0
```

In the sample text, "some text" is various descriptors for electrical devices, e.g. "RATING=63MW", "REFDES=R123". It may contain whitespace but not newlines.

The furthest I've gotten yet is the expression

```
((\n|^)I((?!misc).)*?'\n)((A.*\n)*(A.*BOM=.*\n)(A.*\n)*)
```

which matches the opposite of what I want, i.e it finds the text blocks that DO contain BOM=. I thought I could switch this by changing `(A.*BOM=.*\n)` to `(?!(A.*BOM=.*\n))` but this did not work.

I'm hoping to use this in Notepad++ when I'm done.

Comment: Would it not be simpler to use a `BufferedReader` for this and just step through line by line? You could start reading when you hit `\nI` and end if the line contains `BOM`, store matches in a collection...has the same effect as regex.

Comment: Can you precise what *some text* is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perhaps try this regex:

```
^I(?:(?!misc).)*'\n(?!(?:A.*\n)*?A.*BOM=)(?:A.*\n)*
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/wC6uE7)

I added a third block where the `BOM=` is instead on a line starting with `C`, where the device being matched because `BOM=` is not on the same line as the consecutive lines beginning with `A`.

Multiline by default matches on every line on Notepad++, so it's usually not necessary to have `(^|\n)`, but you can revert it if you need it.

I also kept `(?:(?!misc).)*` in because you had it in your expression, although it doesn't have to do anything with your sample data.

`(?!(?:A.*\n)*?A.*BOM=)` is what's making the match fail when there's a `BOM=` in the lines. It's a negative lookahead which will prevent a match only if `A.*BOM=` matches after any number of lines of `(?:A.*\n)*?` (i.e. lines beginning with `A`).

Comment: This looks promising! I'll test a few things out and let you know if I need any clarification. I definitely need to get more handy with lookaheads and lookbacks. And yes, the Misc part was something I need, although it doesn't come up in this MWE. Thanks!

Comment: @SSilk Sure thing. Do let me know if there are tweaks to be done :) I should be around for the next few hours.

Comment: I tried your expression in regexpal.com's regex tester with the sample text I provided, and it works fine there, but when I try it in Notepad++ with the same text, nothing is found. I'm doing this by pasting the same text into a blank file, and in the find dialog, using "Regular expression" and your expression verbatim. I've tried it with and without ". matches newline". Is there some part of the syntax that would be different in NPP? Thanks.

Comment: OK, figured it out. Each line in my file ends with both a carriage return and linefeed (this seems to be NPP's default), so in your expression I had to change `\n` to `\r\n`.

Comment: @SSilk Ah, cool then. I was trying to solve something else ^^; NPP is not defaulted to `\r\n`, it's just that when you paste there, it keeps all the characters. If your original file had `\r\n`, then it'll have it too. If it had only `\n`, NPP would have that only. You can see the `\r` and `\n` if you do View > Show Symbol > End of Line. `CR` is `\r` and `LF` is `\n`.